# Get all documents from a sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, spfile

I want to retrieve all the existing documents from an SPDocumentLibrary in order to print them so I've tried this way but then I got stucked :

```
using (SPSite mysite = SPContext.Current.Site)
{
    using (SPWeb myweb = mysite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPDocumentLibrary myDocLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)myweb.Lists["DocLibrary"];
        SPList myList = SPContext.Current.List;
        SPFileCollection myFiles = myList.;
        foreach (SPListItem myItem in myList.Items)
        {
            //adding each found file to my SPFileCollection
            myFiles.Add(myItem.File);
        }
    }
}
```

but the SPFileCollection.Add function takes more than the file argument !
so I guess this way don't work , is there any other way to recover my files ?

Comment: Glolita, few questions I see some errors in the code like here: SPFileCollection myFiles = myList.; myList.[WHAT]? Also, why are you adding the files in SPFileCollection, and what are you planning to do next with this collection?

Comment: as I said I need to print all these found documents and I need to put them in a collection so that I can apply my printing method on them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SPFileCollection` is probably a bad idea. I suppose it's too coupled to the internal SharePoint storage behavior.

Replace it with a simple `List<SPFile>`. This will be easier and works.

A side note, your approach is not taking care of files in subfolders. You should write a small recursive method to get all documents :

```
private IEnumerable<SPFile> GetAllDocuments() { 
    var myweb = SPContext.Current.Web;
    SPDocumentLibrary myDocLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)myweb.Lists["DocLibrary"];

    return ExploreFolder(myDocLib.RootFolder);


}

private IEnumerable<SPFile> ExploreFolder(SPFolder folder) { 
    foreach(SPFile file in folder.Files)
    {
        yield return file;
    }
    foreach(SPFolder subFolder in folder.SubFolders)
    {
        foreach(SPFile file in ExploreFolder(subFolder))
        {
            yield return file;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @glolita, I've changed my code a bit. I think your site and web variables were messy. Here is a way to execute the code in the current Web. Especially, I did not used the using keyword to avoid disposing context web?§

Comment: Yeah, you don't need or want to dispose of the current Web object, so removing that was a good tack. I would go so far as to explicitly cast myweb as an SPWeb object because it's easier to work with in Visual Studio but I guess that's in the eye of the beholder...