# List out all files inside all folders of Document library using Server object model

Tags: document-library, file, server

```
SPFileCollection foler = pdflibrary.RootFolder.Files;
```

Above code line will only give files outside folder. How can get all files inside and outside folder into `SPFileCollection`. What is the easiest way.

Comment: This may help http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67929/how-to-get-splistitemcollection-from-a-spfolder and http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/48959/get-all-documents-from-a-sharepoint-document-library

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet:

```
var query = new SPQuery();
query.Folder = pdflibrary.RootFolder;                        
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\""; 
var listItems = list.GetItems(query);
```